# Simple python function integer error?

Tags: python

Why does this function give the error message "You need to type an integer," even though I type and integer for the input?

```
def readValue():
    while True:
        pressure = input('Type pressure: ')
        if pressure == int(pressure):
            return pressure
        else:
            print('You need to type an integer.')
```

Comment: `'2' == 2`  is always `
False
`

Comment: do a `print type(pressure)` right after getting the input.

Answer (score 1):

This line assigns the string input to `pressure`

```
pressure = input('Type pressure: ')
```

Then you compare the string to the converted `int` of `pressure`

```
if pressure == int(pressure):
```

These will never be equal.

If you are trying to do some simple input validation, you could use `try`/`except` and check for the exception `ValueError`, which indicates a failure to convert to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is Python 3. In that case, `input()` returns a string.

The string `3` is not equal to the result of `int("3")`, so the test fails.

Answer (score 1):

```
pressure = input('Type pressure: ')
```

The line is invalid for following task,
According to me the task you want to perform can be done as follows

```
def readValue():
    while True:
        pressure = input('Type pressure: ')
        try:
            pressure = int(pressure)
            return pressure
        except:
            print('You need to type an integer.')
            return 0
print readValue()
```

try it and it will work !

try/except will work in this type of task.....
try will convert pressure to integer value and if any error occurs then it will go to except part. :)